# React Virtualized: Table rows get cut off when autoHeight is on

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I am currently trying to implement React Virtualized to replace an laggy table but am running into an issue. I am using `WindowScroller`, `AutoSizer`, `Table`, and `Column` from React Virtualized,

In my 400 row table, about 30 rows appear before they stop showing up (as in those DOM elements have not been rendered). However, the table appears to be the correct height. Here is a picture to help visualize:

[image]

From what I can tell, the culprit is (or related to) `autoHeight` on the `<Table />` element. When I remove it, I can scroll through all the row elements within the Table. However, this breaks the desired functionality of being able to scroll the page, not the Table.

Things I have tested so far:

- It occurred to me that the issue might be with the `scrollElement` on `WindowScroller` since the container element for my table has `overflow: scroll; height: 100vh`. When I tried setting the `scrollElement` property to this element none of my rows would render. For testing purposes, I also tried removing this container so that `window` would handle scrolling, but this didn't solve the bug either.
- I have tried replicating [this](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/WindowScroller/WindowScroller.example.js) example as closely as possible, but no dice so far.

Finally, here is a simplified code snippet:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Table, Column, WindowScroller, AutoSizer } from "react-virtualized";
import "react-virtualized/styles.css";
import "./style.scss";

class AnalyticsResponsesReportTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    ...
  }

  //Methods...

  render() {
    const data = this.props.values.data;

    return (
      <div className="AnalyticsResponsesReportTable">
        {data.length && (
          <WindowScroller>
            {({
              height,
              isScrolling,
              registerChild,
              onChildScroll,
              scrollTop
            }) => (
              <div>
                <AutoSizer disableHeight>
                  {({ width }) => (
                    <Table
                      ref="Table"
                      headerHeight={40}
                      height={height}
                      width={width}
                      autoHeight
                      rowCount={data.length}
                      rowHeight={40}
                      rowGetter={({ index }) => data[index]}
                      className="AnalyticsResponsesReportTable__table"
                      onRowClick={this.handleRowClick}
                    >
                     //Columns rendering here
                    </Table>
                  )}
                </AutoSizer>
              </div>
            )}
          </WindowScroller>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AnalyticsResponsesReportTable;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying out *many* different combinations, the root issue was that I had not set `scrollTop={scrollTop}` on `Table`. I also needed to set `scrollElement` to the appropriate container. The issue took so long to solve since both are needed, and I guess I had just tested one without the other

Comment: In case anyone runs into this issue again here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6md5st9h/28/

You can see my issue occurring if you remove `scrollTop={scrollTop}`